# Compile Error: Cannot find symbol of array.length

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm creating a method to be able to "print a histogram," and I'm trying to get it to reference the histogramData.length, to be able to loop and build each row, but it's not recognizing histogramData.length in the method.

I have the code in 2 separate files, one for main and one to build the methods.

Main looks like:

```
import becker.robots.*;
public class DrawHistogram extends Object
{   public static void main(String[] args)
   {   City Edmonds = new City(12, 12);
       HistogramRobot drawingBot = new HistogramRobot(Edmonds, 1, 1, Direction.EAST, 1000);
       HistogramPrinter histPrinter = new HistogramPrinter();

  int [] histogramData = new int[7];

     histogramData[0] = 3; // The first element holds 3
     histogramData[1] = 5; // The second element holds 5
     histogramData[2] = 1; // The third element holds 1
     histogramData[3] = 0; // The fourth element holds 0
     histogramData[4] = 4; // The fifth element holds 4
     histogramData[5] = 2; // The sixth element holds 2
     histogramData[6] = 1; // The seventh element holds 1

    drawingBot.drawRow();
   }
}
```

And my method file looks like

```
import becker.robots.*;
class HistogramRobot extends Robot
{
HistogramRobot(City c, int st, int ave, Direction dir, int num)
{
    super(c, st, ave, dir, num);
}    
 public void drawRow()
 {
    for(int counter = 0; counter < histogramData.length; counter++)
       {
          if( histogramData[counter] == 0) 
         {
         this.turnRight();
                 this.move();
                 this.turnLeft();
                 }
              for( int histoDrop = 0; histoDrop < histogramData[counter]; histoDrop++)
              {
         this.putThing();
                 this.move();
          }
        this.turnAround();
        for (int moves = 0; moves < histogramData[counter]; moves++)
           {
           this.move();
           }
        this.turnLeft();
        this.move();
        this.turnLeft();
     }
  }

 public void turnRight()
        {
    this.turnLeft();
  this.turnLeft();
  this.turnLeft();
 }

 public void turnAround()
 {
    this.turnLeft();
  this.turnLeft();
 }
}
```

And the error I'm getting for each mention of "histogramData" including "histogramData.length"

```
HistogramRobot.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
            for( int histoDrop = 0; histoDrop < histogramData[counter]; histoDrop++)
                                                ^
  symbol:   variable histogramData
  location: class HistogramRobot
```

What's causing the error and how can I fix it?

//I'm sorry! I could not get the spacing in the second part to work in my favor, let me know if you need clarification to answer.

Comment: Your problem is you don't define an array called histogramData anywhere in your HistogramRobot class. Try pass it into the drawRow method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have declared your

```
int [] histogramData = new int[7];
```

in your `main` method and so its scope is limited to this method.

Pass it as a parameter to where it is needed

Such as

```
drawingBot.drawRow(histogramData);
```

and you method declaration would be

```
public void drawRow(int [] histogramData)
```

Comment: histogramData is not even in the same class as where you try to use it. just to add a bit :)

Comment: Forgive me if I seem like I know what I'm talking about... but I have no idea where I would put it otherwise? Should I put it with the creation of the drawRow method, or in a new file entirely?

Comment: @TaylerMaybe Its OK, it does not look like you know what you are talking about ;-).  I have updated my answer

Comment: I KNOW IT SAYS TO AVOID COMMENTS LIKE "THANKS" BUT THAT HONESTLY HELPED ME MORE THAN YOU COULD EVER KNOW SO THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU.